# iOS Obj-C Hooking Converting Hex to String

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos

I am trying to hook a simple function in Theos:

```
- (_Bool)sendData:(id)arg1 {
    NSLog(@"%@", arg1);
    _Bool r = %orig;
    return r;
};
```

But the output I get is in hex:

```
<3c736f61 70656e76 3a456e76 656c6f70 6520786d 6c6e733a 736f6170 656e763d>
```

I have tried a few conversion codes found from stack overflow but have had no luck printing the ASCII text from that.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The output is in hex because that is the way NSLog displays it. Using a type of `id` is a bad idea, use the real type. We can't tell what should happen it we don't know the type? `NSData`, `NSString`, something else?

Comment: Yes I know, I would like to know how I can output it in ASCII. I've tried converting to Char *. or used [arg1 UTF8String] no luck

Comment: @Zaph you don't seem to understand me, I'm hooking a function, I don't know the type.

Comment: Add your code to the question and change id to the real type.

Comment: Is that: "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=" what you're suppose to get?

Comment: Use `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([arg1 class]))` for determine object class.

Comment: @Larme YES!  correct!

Comment: @rock88 Yes, but I cannot be sure that the type will always be the same all the time.

Comment: @rock88 just in case you're wondering the class output NSConcreteMutableData

Comment: if ([arg1 isKindOfClass:[NSData class]){NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)arg1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];}. Note that for your thing, there is a few of the encoding that works.

Comment: @Larme Wonderful that worked! You wanna place an answer then I'll be able to mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you data output, your response is: `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=`

```
if ([arg1 isKindOfClass:[NSData class])
{
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)arg1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

I tried various encodings, and `NSUTF8StringEncoding` wasn't the only one to give the correct response. So you may want to check which one is really the appropriate one.